# Why is my NVIDIA driver loaded but not detected by X.org?

Tags: x11, drivers, xorg, nvidia

I'm using a Debian 10 system with X.org installed, LightDM as display manager and GNOME as desktop environment. When I start LightDM, only one physical display starts. I have two displays, one internal, driven by my integrated intel graphics, one external HDMI, driven by my discrete nvidia graphics. I have set up NVIDIA optimus using bumblebee/primus, so I can use my integrated intel graphics to drive the display whilst running applications on my discrete card. When I start LightDM, the X server only uses the internal screen whilst my monitor remains in standby. I need to use an Xorg config file even though its not recommended because otherwise Xorg won't detect my external display.

/etc/X11/xorg.conf:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "Accel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "Backlight"             # <str>
        #Option     "CustomEDID"            # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <str>
        #Option     "Present"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ColorKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "Tiling"                # [<bool>]
        #Option     "LinearFramebuffer"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWRotation"            # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VSync"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapbuffersWait"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "TripleBuffer"          # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvPreferOverlay"       # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HotPlug"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ReprobeOutputs"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "XvMC"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "VirtualHeads"          # <i>
        #Option     "TearFree"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "PerCrtcPixmaps"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FallbackDebug"         # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushBatches"     # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugFlushCaches"      # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DebugWait"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "BufferCache"           # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "intel"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False"ss,
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"               # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"              # <i>
        #Option     "WrappedFB"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "GLXVBlank"             # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ZaphodHeads"           # <str>
        #Option     "PageFlip"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "SwapLimit"             # <i>
        #Option     "AsyncUTSDFS"           # [<bool>]
        #Option     "AccelMethod"           # <str>
        #Option     "DRI"                   # <i>
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

lspci | grep NVIDIA to show my graphics are detected:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f99 (rev a1)
```

lsmod | grep nvidia to show that the nvidia drivers are loaded:

```
nvidia_modeset       1232896  1
nvidia              34164736  18 nvidia_modeset
```

My LightDM config file has no xserver-config field set so it will use /etc/X11/xorg.conf

I can't post the entire X.org log as it's too many characters. The three most notable lines are:

```
[  9581.561] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  9581.562] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nvidia
[  9581.562] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is my graphics card detected by lspci and the drivers by lsmod, but Xorg says that the driver doesn't exist?
2. How can I make it so that X.org does detect the drivers?

P.S.: The nouveau drivers are not loaded, and not mentioned in the Xorg config so they shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Please ask here https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov unfortunately the nvidia forums have been of no help to me whatsoever to my experience. They blamed me for pretending to have a problem that was unfixable, when i genuinely had an issue. I will try again however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Debian Rolling Release (unstable/sid) and it works now. I really don't know what the problem was, something about bumblebee/primus I think. After the upgrade I now have Xorg 1.20.11 so I can use NVIDIA Optimus natively. One driver reinstall + purge later, it works great.